# Change the values in a column

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a column in R which looks like below:

```
won <- c("\001", rep("\\0",3), "\001")

 won
\001
 \\0
 \\0
 \\0
 \\0
\001
```

There are two possible values, \0 or \001

I am wondering what the most efficient route is to change these values to 
0 (for \0) and 1 (for \001). I'm sure gsub() is one option, it's jut not clear if 
it's the way to go to alter two separate string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case:

```
2 - nchar(won)
```

Here is another option:

```
ifelse(won == "\001", 1, 0)
```