# Remove escapes from a string, or, "how can I get \ out of the way?"

Tags: string, r, escaping

Escape characters cause a lot of trouble in R, as evidenced by previous questions:

1. [Change the values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046357/change-the-values-in-a-column/10046412#10046412)
2. [Can R paste() output "\"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379681/can-r-paste-output)
3. [Replacing escaped double quotes by double quotes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697247/replacing-escaped-double-quotes-by-double-quotes-in-r)
4. [How to gsub('%', '\%', ... in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031999/how-to-gsub-in-r)

Many of these previous questions could be simplified to special cases of "How can I get \ out of my way?"

Is there a simple way to do this?

For example, I can find no arguments to `gsub` that will remove all escapes from the following:

```
 test <- c('\01', '\\001')
```

Comment: `\0` is the nul string.  R hasn't allowed those in strings for a few versions.  Which version of R are you using?

Comment: @Josh: 2.14. Is there no way to extract "0" from "\0"?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to remove all instances of "\?" where "\" is taken literally and "?" means any single character?  Or do you just want to strip all instances of"\" except when it's "\\" ?  I'd still go with the regex construction ` [\\]{1,}`  . Edit: heck, even the parser for edits here messes up escapes :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'd like to strip all of the instances of escapes, even with "\\". regex is fine but I am not proficient.

Comment: No, because `\01` isn't what you think it is; try `cat(test,'\n',sep=" "); print(test)`.  You're confusing the actual string (the output from `cat`) with the printed representation of the string (the output from `print`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difficulty here is that `"\1"`, although it's printed with two glyphs, is actually, in R's view a single character.  And in fact, it's the very same character as `"\001"` and `"\01"`:

```
nchar("\1")
# [1] 1
nchar("\001")
# [1] 1
identical("\1", "\001")
# [1] TRUE
```

So, you *can* in general remove all backslashes with something like this:

```
(test <- c("\\hi\\", "\n", "\t", "\\1", "\1", "\01", "\001"))
# [1] "\\hi\\" "\n"     "\t"      "\\1"    "\001"   "\001"   "\001"  
eval(parse(text=gsub("\\", "", deparse(test), fixed=TRUE)))
# [1] "hi"  "n"   "t"   "1"   "001" "001" "001"
```

But, as you can see, `"\1"`, `"\01"`, and `\001"` will all be rendered as `001`, (since to R they are all just different names for `"\001"`).

---

**EDIT**: For more on the use of `"\"` in escape sequences, and on the great variety of characters that can be represented using them (including the disallowed nul string mentioned by Joshua Ulrich in a comment above), see [this section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants) of the R language definition.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue - if you want any \x where x is a character then I am not sure how, I wish I knew, but to fix it for a specific escape sequence,. say \n then you can do

```
new = gsub("\n","",old,fixed=T)
```

in my case, I only had \n