# Having trouble converting columns of character to factor in datatypes in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I am attempting to turn two columns of character data into factors, so I can analyze their "levels".

The problem is at the very end of the code.
One of the two columns was processed fine.  It turns out some strings when I run the "levels" command on it.

```
> levels(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips$highestOffenseDesc)
[1] "AGG ROBBERY BY ASSAULT"    "AGG ROBBERY/DEADLY WEAPON" "BURG NON RESIDENCE SHEDS"  "BURGLARY NON RESIDENCE"   
[5] "BURGLARY OF RESIDENCE"     "ROBBERY BY ASSAULT"        "ROBBERY BY THREAT"
```

When I run "levels" on the other column, I see that its data appears to have had trouble in the conversion from character -> factor data types.

```
> levels(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips$NIBRS_OffenseDesc)
[1] "Burglary / \nBreaking & Entering" "Robbery"
```

I was hoping someone could help me understand what is happening here, and how to correct it.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

####
####  Import 2014 neighborhood economic data
####
# Import data
austin2014_data_raw <- read_csv('https://data.austintexas.gov/resource/hcnj-rei3.csv', na = '')
glimpse(austin2014_data_raw)
nrow(austin2014_data_raw)

# Clean it: Remove NAs
austin2014_data <- na.omit(austin2014_data_raw)
nrow(austin2014_data) # now there's one less row.

columnSelection <- c("Zip Code", "Population below poverty level", "Median household income", "Unemployment", "Median rent", "Percentage of rental units in poor condition")

## Our neighborhood economic data subset
austin2014_data_selection <- subset(austin2014_data, select=columnSelection)
names(austin2014_data_selection)

# Extract the zip codes for mapping & comparison with crime data
zipCodesOfData <- austin2014_data_selection$`Zip Code`



####
####  Import crime data
####

# Import data
austinCrime2014_data_raw <- read_csv('https://data.austintexas.gov/resource/7g8v-xxja.csv', na = '')
glimpse(austinCrime2014_data_raw)
nrow(austinCrime2014_data_raw)

# Select and rename required columns
columnSelection_Crime <- c("GO Location Zip", "GO Highest Offense Desc", "Highest NIBRS/UCR Offense Description")
austinCrime_dataset <- select(austinCrime2014_data_raw, one_of(columnSelection_Crime))
names(austinCrime_dataset) <- c("zipcode", "highestOffenseDesc", "NIBRS_OffenseDesc")
glimpse(austinCrime_dataset)
nrow(austinCrime_dataset)

# Filter crime data by zipcodes available in the neighborhood economic data subset
austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips <- filter(austinCrime_dataset, zipcode %in% zipCodesOfData)
glimpse(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips)
nrow(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips)
typeof(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips)

####
####  Convert our crime data subset from string/char data into factorized data so we can see levels
####

# let's make the character data columns c("highestOffenseDesc", "NIBRS_OffenseDesc") into factors so we can check its levels
glimpse(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips) # characters
cols <- c("highestOffenseDesc", "NIBRS_OffenseDesc") # columns with character datatype to convert to factor datatype
austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips[cols] <- lapply(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips[cols], factor)
glimpse(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips) # factors

View(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips)
levels(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips$highestOffenseDesc) #--> looks good
levels(austinCrime2014_data_selected_zips$NIBRS_OffenseDesc) # output is weird:  "Burglary / \nBreaking & Entering" "Robbery"
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to do more cleaning of   the character data and get rid of the  \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the conversion. It is simply showing you what is actually there: The 'cell' of the data sheet contains a new line character: `\n`.

If you wish to clean it up, you can use `gsub` to replace the escape characters. Or possibly just assign a new name to that level.

Take a look here: [Remove escapes from a string, or, "how can I get \ out of the way?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076507/remove-escapes-from-a-string-or-how-can-i-get-out-of-the-way)

Comment: Thank you.  As a pertinent followup, I am having an issue with a variable in the same code.  The variable is "zipCodesOfData".  When I use this command: "View(zipCodesOfData)" I get this strange output: http://imgur.com/tvbK0wz

I was hoping you might know what is causing this problem... It's very strange b/c it's as if there's a sort of "ghost" cell containing a string of the entire zipcode list.

Comment: @PatrickMeaney, What is `class(zipCodesOfData)`? My guess is that it is a tibble, and you are expecting numeric. What you are seeing is not a cell in the data, but the title of the column. Either that, or `view` does weird things to factors. Personally I never use `view` so I am not the best person to ask.